# How to update return value of method with another method?

Tags: c#, methods

This is my first question. Please correct me if I have some mistake. THX

```
//Form.cs
Sweet sweet = new Sweet();
Donut donut = new Donut();
//classify the condition with int i;
if (i==0)
   score.Text=sweet.TambahPoin().ToString();
else if (i==1)
   score.Text=donut.DoublePoin().ToString();
```

This is the parent class

```
class Sweet
{
    //field
    int m_poin;

    //properties
    public int Poin
    {
        get{return m_poin;}
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
                m_poin = 0;
            else
                m_poin = value;
        }
    }

    //Method

    public int TambahPoin()
    {
        Poin += 10;
        return Poin;
    }
}
```

I want to make a method that will double the TambahPoin() with condition it will add the score before.
if the initial Poin = 100 and then call  TambahPoin() method will become 110 after that i want to call DoublePoin method so the score become 110+20=130.(I have tried with my own solution before but the score becomes 20 not 130)

Comment: Please post your full code.

Comment: From : return Poin; To : return m_poin;

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
public int TambahPoin()
{
    m_poin += 10;
    return m_poin;
}

public int DoublePoin()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        TambahPoin();
    }
    return m_poin;
}

public int IncreasePoin()
{
    if (m_poin == 100) TambahPoin();
    DoublePoin();
    return m_poin;
}
```

Inside the class you can work with private fields and is quicker because you are not calling get/set methods from properties.